# alertdialog redirection to url

Tags: android

I used the android alertdialog in order to redirect to a url, the redirection should go according to user choice, here is the code:

```
   final CharSequence[]stringArray =  {"1" ,"2" , "3"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Press selected name");
    builder.setItems(stringArray, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            String st = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9QyKNQ0uVc";
            String st2 = "https://www.youtube.com/";
            if (stringArray.toString().equals("1")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                         Uri.parse(st));
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
            else if (stringArray.toString().contains("2")) {                

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                             Uri.parse(st2));
                        startActivity(intent);                  
                                    }
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

but when I click 1 or 2 there is no redirection to the url
what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Have you tried to debug and check?

Answer (score 0):

You are checking your arrays items which is not valid way to implement. You need to check for selected item's id which you can get from onclick method only.

As the array count starts from "0" so can check your selected item with "0 to 2" where your 0 will be considered as "1" selected and so on.

Check out below code:

```
    final CharSequence[] stringArray = { "1", "2", "3" };
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Press selected name");
    builder.setItems(stringArray, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            String st = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9QyKNQ0uVc";
            String st2 = "https://www.youtube.com/";
            if (item == 0)
            // if (stringArray.toString().equals("1"))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse(st));
                startActivity(intent);
            } else if (item == 1)
            // else if (stringArray.toString().contains("2"))
            {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                        .parse(st2));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use following code:-

```
final CharSequence[] stringArray = { "1", "2", "3" };

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

builder.setTitle("Press selected name");

builder.setItems(stringArray, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position) {

String st = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9QyKNQ0uVc";

String st2 = "https://www.youtube.com/";

if (position == 0) {

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(st));

startActivity(intent);

} 

else if (position == 1) {

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(st2));

startActivity(intent);

} 

else if (position == 2) {

// write some code

}

}

});

AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

alert.show();
```